# The Most Efficient Way of Update a Column

Tags: sql

I am quite new to SQL, so I apologize if I am asking simple question.

So, I have a table `CompProd` which contains companies and their products, as follows:

```
Company Name   |  Product Name
--------------------------------
 Company Alpha |    Prod_A1
 Company Alpha |    Prod_A2
 Company Alpha |    Prod_A3
 Company Alpha |    Prod_B1
 Company Beta  |    Prod_A4
 Company Beta  |    Prod_B2
 Company Beta  |    Prod_B3
```

And there is a table `ProdCat` which contains products' categories, as follows:

```
Product Name   |  Product Category
------------------------------------
   Prod_A1     |           A
   Prod_A2     |           A
   Prod_A3     |           A
   Prod_A4     |           A
   Prod_B1     |           B
   Prod_B2     |           B
   Prod_B3     |           B
```

What I want to do is, first add a column `Product Category` in table `CompProd`, then fill in the column from table `ProdCat`.

The following is my code:

```
ALTER dbo.CompProd
ADD Product_Category VCHAR(20)

UPDATE dbo.CompProd
Set dbo.CompProd.Product_Category = (
                                SELECT cat.Product_Category
                                FROM   dbo.CompProd comp LEFT JOIN dbo.ProdCat cat
                                ON comp.Product_Name = cat.Product_name
                              )
```

Since each of the table has millions of rows, it takes quite a lot of time to run the above code chunk.

Is there more efficient way to do this?

Many thanks.

Comment: why did you use left join in inner query ?

Comment: Are you sure that you have denormalize your data? Why not join the category when required?

Answer (score 0):

```
            CompProd   
  Company Name   |  Product_Id
    --------------------------------
     Company Alpha |    1
     Company Beta  |    2

             products
Product Name   |  Product Category | id
-----------------------------------------
   Prod_A1     |           A       | 1
   Prod_A2     |           A       | 2
   Prod_A3     |           A       | 3
   Prod_A4     |           A       | 4
   Prod_B1     |           B       | 5
   Prod_B2     |           B       | 6
```

if edit table structure to this.Is not this better? 
you do not need to update 10000 record!.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Yes, I agree this is a easy way to do this. But the team who review the data after me would like to keep the original format rather than give it a new ID column.